# A question on the Wronskian

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $f(z),g(z)$ be two complex-valued functions defined in some domain $D$. Suppose we want to show that

$$f(z)+g(z)\neq 0 \tag1$$

for all $z\in D$. I think I'm right in saying we can use the Wronskian to achieve this. If we compute
$$W[f,g](z) = \left|\begin{array}{ll} f(z) & g(z) \\ f'(z) & g'(z) \end{array}\right| = f(z)g'(z)-g(z)f'(z),$$ then we can conclude that $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent if we can show there exists a $z_0\in D$ such that $$W[f,g](z_0)\neq 0.$$

**My question is:** does proving linear independence of $f$ and $g$ prove (1) for all $z\in D$ ?

My concern is, even if $f$ and $g$ are non-zero at the same time for all $z\in D$, what happens if we permit $f(z_1)=0$ and $f(z_1)\neq 0$ for some $z_1\in D$, or vice-versa. Would the same argument hold? Or maybe my argument is incorrect in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to conclude that $f(z)+g(z)\ne0,\forall z \in D$ from the linear independence of $f$ and $g.$ If $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent the same holds for $\bar{f}=f-f(0)$ and $\bar{g}=g-g(0).$ Clearly, $\bar{f}(0)+\bar{g}(0)=0.$

Even if we assume that $f$ and $g$ do not vanish on $D$ the conclusion doesn't hold. Take $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C};|z|<1\},$ $f(z)=z+5$ and $g(z)=z^2-5.$ $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent and $f(0)+g(0)=0.$